# Stuck subtracting binary numbers

Tags: binary

For this question i have to subtact two binary numbers. The resualt has to be a negative number but i am always getting the wrong answer. Heres what i have done:

> 57 - 184
>
> 111001 - 10111000
>
> Then i flip 10111000 is its 01000110
>
> Add one on the end 01000111
>
> Then i did this:
>
> (Lost about here)
>
> 111001 + 01000111 = 10000000.
>
> Then you subtact that from a -128 or -256. (I'm lost please help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
111001 - 10111000

Because left is smaller than right operand, pre-add 100000000
(100000000 is where you want to have sign bit after)

  100000000
+    111001  
-----------
  100111001

Then just subtract

  100111001
-  10111000
-----------
   10000001

Result (8bits) = -127
```

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure i understand it now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use filp as this 010111000 is its 101000110 Use extra 0 when there is a 1 in first binary!